# What is the meaning of this Microsoft EULA message?

Tags: software-installation, fonts

```
 ┌─────────────────┤ Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE                           
 │                                                                             
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement         
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a        
 │ single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software         
 │ accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include    
 │ associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic            
 │ documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your        
 │ rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be      
 │ bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of        
 │ this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.                            
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>                                       
 │                                                                           │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more information. Where did you see this message? What were you doing when you saw it? We need to know some details before we can help.

Comment: This message is quite clear. You need to accept the licence. Press Tab, then Enter.

Comment: The meaning seems clear to me? Oh and what to -do- there is hit the "tab" to highlight OK to agree.

Comment: @terdon The question is clear. It may be a duplicate, but not unclear at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 OK, I have no idea what this is referring to. The OP didn't say what they were doing, when this happened, where they saw it or anything. If you know what it is, I am happy to reopen, but please edit the question yourself and include the command that can generate this message.

Comment: I can explain this in an answer. This is MS Fonts EULA.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I bet he's trying to install Wine.

Answer (score 4):

The message in the popup window is asking if you want to accept the Microsoft **E**nd **U**ser **L**icense **A**greement (EULA) when installing proprietary Microsoft TrueType core fonts.

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to accept the EULA in the Microsoft TrueType core fonts window that pops up. This pop-up window sometimes gets covered up by other open windows when installing Microsoft TrueType core fonts from the Software application, making it difficult to accept the EULA in order to continue the installation of Microsoft TrueType core fonts.

Answer (score 1):

This message appears when you install Microsoft fonts (`ttf-mscorefonts-installer`), or `ubuntu-restricted-extras` that installs these fonts too.

The message asks to accept End User Licence (EULA).

You can do it by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>